Updating Master-Detail relationship
Having these entities (all of them have their constructors and getters/setters):
@Entity
public class Venta {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "numero")
    private Integer numeroComprobante;
    @Column(name = "fecha_venta")
    private LocalDateTime fecha;
    @Column()
    private String nombreCliente;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "venta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Detalle> detalles;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "venta_detalle")
public class Detalle {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Double cantidad;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "venta_id")
    private Venta venta;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "producto_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Producto producto;
}

@Entity
public class Producto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String nombre;
    private String descripcion;
    private Double precio;
    private LocalDateTime fechaAlta;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "producto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Detalle> detalles;
}

I am trying to implement the update functionality of Venta and its Detail with this code (I have a VentaRequest and VentaResponse to handle incoming and outcoming data):
public VentaResponse update(Long id, VentaRequest ventaRequest) {
        Optional<Venta> venta = this.ventaRepository.findById(id);

        if (venta.isEmpty())
            throw new ProcesoException("Venta con ID " + id + " no existe.");

        venta.get().setNombreCliente(ventaRequest.getNombreCliente());

        for (Detalle detalle: venta.get().getDetalles())
            this.detalleRepository.delete(detalle);
        
        List<Detalle> detalles = new ArrayList<>();
        Detalle detalle;
        Optional<Producto> producto;

        for (DetalleRequest detalleRequest: ventaRequest.getDetalles()) {
            detalle = new Detalle();

            producto = this.productoRepository.findById(detalleRequest.getProductoId());
            if (producto.isEmpty())
                throw new ProcesoException("Producto con ID " + detalleRequest.getProductoId() + "no encontrado.");

            detalle.setCantidad(detalleRequest.getCantidad());
            detalle.setVenta(venta.get());
            detalle.setProducto(producto.get());

            detalles.add(detalle);
        }

        venta.get().setDetalles(detalles);

        Venta ventaActualizada = this.ventaRepository.save(venta.get());

        return this.convertirVentaAVentaResponse(ventaActualizada);
    }

When calling this function I get this error:

A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer
referenced by the owning entity instance:
net.comercial.ventas.ventas.Venta.detalles

What I have tried:

Changing the orphanRemoval in Venta to false
Changing the cascade configuration or Delete Rule and Update Rule for Venta-Detalle relationship in Postgres to Cascade
Deleting venta related detail before updating venta and its new detail

Nothing works.

If Hibernate detects that a collection it is managing has been replaced or no longer referenced, it throws this error. FYR: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-orphanremoval
Root Cause:
You are directly deleting the Detalle entities in your update service.
this.detalleRepository.delete(detalle); 

Solution:
Instead of deleting the Detalle entities directly, clear the collection and manage it within the parent entity. FYR:
@Transactional
public VentaResponse update(Long id, VentaRequest ventaRequest) {
    Optional<Venta> optionalVenta = this.ventaRepository.findById(id);

    if (optionalVenta.isEmpty())
        throw new ProcesoException("Venta con ID " + id + " no existe.");

    Venta venta = optionalVenta.get();
    venta.setNombreCliente(ventaRequest.getNombreCliente());

    // Clear the existing detalles to avoid orphan issues
    venta.getDetalles().clear();

    List<Detalle> detalles = new ArrayList<>();
    Optional<Producto> producto;

    for (DetalleRequest detalleRequest : ventaRequest.getDetalles()) {
        Detalle detalle = new Detalle();

        producto = this.productoRepository.findById(detalleRequest.getProductoId());
        if (producto.isEmpty())
            throw new ProcesoException("Producto con ID " + detalleRequest.getProductoId() + " no encontrado.");

        detalle.setCantidad(detalleRequest.getCantidad());
        detalle.setVenta(venta);
        detalle.setProducto(producto.get());

        detalles.add(detalle);
    }

    venta.setDetalles(detalles);

    Venta ventaActualizada = this.ventaRepository.save(venta);

    return this.convertirVentaAVentaResponse(ventaActualizada);
}

